# Grouping by date range with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, group-by, pandas-groupby

I am looking to group by two columns: user_id and date; however, if the dates are close enough, I want to be able to consider the two entries part of the same group and group accordingly. Date is m-d-y

```
user_id     date       val
1           1-1-17     1
2           1-1-17     1
3           1-1-17     1
1           1-1-17     1
1           1-2-17     1
2           1-2-17     1
2           1-10-17    1
3           2-1-17     1
```

The grouping would group by user_id and dates +/- 3 days from each other. so the group by summing val would look like:

```
user_id     date       sum(val)
1           1-2-17     3
2           1-2-17     2
2           1-10-17    1
3           1-1-17     1
3           2-1-17     1
```

Any way someone could think of that this could be done (somewhat) easily? I know there are some problematic aspects of this. for example, what to do if the dates string together endlessly with three days apart. but the exact data im using only has 2 values per person..

Thanks!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'd convert this to a `datetime` column and then use `pd.TimeGrouper`:

```
dates =  pd.to_datetime(df.date, format='%m-%d-%y')
print(dates)
0   2017-01-01
1   2017-01-01
2   2017-01-01
3   2017-01-01
4   2017-01-02
5   2017-01-02
6   2017-01-10
7   2017-02-01
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]

df = (df.assign(date=dates).set_index('date')
        .groupby(['user_id', pd.TimeGrouper('3D')])
        .sum()
        .reset_index())    
print(df)
   user_id       date  val
0        1 2017-01-01    3
1        2 2017-01-01    2
2        2 2017-01-10    1
3        3 2017-01-01    1
4        3 2017-01-31    1
```

---

Similar solution using `pd.Grouper`:

```
df = (df.assign(date=dates)
        .groupby(['user_id', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='3D')])
        .sum()
        .reset_index())
print(df)
   user_id       date  val
0        1 2017-01-01    3
1        2 2017-01-01    2
2        2 2017-01-10    1
3        3 2017-01-01    1
4        3 2017-01-31    1
```

Update: `TimeGrouper` will be deprecated in future versions of pandas, so `Grouper` would be preferred in this scenario (thanks for the heads up, Vaishali!).

Comment: I always afraid to touch any time related question ... LOL btw +1

Comment: Amazing, never used grouper somehow

Comment: `Grouper` is `TimeGrouper`

Comment: Thanks both :) @Wen, yeah I used to run away from date problems as well. Also, yeah, you're right, the only difference being TimeGrouper needs the index to be a datetime index.

Comment: @Wen It was my first choice, but the datetime column seems to disappear... uff... I didn't like `reset_index` either but no choice..

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ Yeah ,i noticed that too :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ sir, may i eat your brain so i may steal your powers? this is awesome!!

Answer (score 2):

I come with a very ugly solution but still work...

```
df=df.sort_values(['user_id','date'])
df['Key']=df.sort_values(['user_id','date']).groupby('user_id')['date'].diff().dt.days.lt(3).ne(True).cumsum()
df.groupby(['user_id','Key'],as_index=False).agg({'val':'sum','date':'first'})

Out[586]: 
   user_id  Key  val       date
0        1    1    3 2017-01-01
1        2    2    2 2017-01-01
2        2    3    1 2017-01-10
3        3    4    1 2017-01-01
4        3    5    1 2017-02-01
```