# pandas group by row on 7 day range for date column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large data frame with around 264k rows that I want to split by 7 day's range, the data frame looks like below-

```
CreatedDate CreatedTime    Symbol   Type
0   7/1/2021    9:30:00 AM  AAPL    SWEEP
1   7/1/2021    9:30:00 AM  TSLA    BLOCK
2   7/1/2021    9:30:00 AM  AAPL    SWEEP
3   7/1/2021    9:30:00 AM  AMD     BLOCK
4   7/1/2021    9:30:01 AM  GOEV    BLOCK
........................................
........................................
264754  9/24/2021   3:59:51 PM  PLTR    SWEEP
264755  9/24/2021   3:59:55 PM  TSLA    SWEEP
264756  9/24/2021   3:59:57 PM  TSLA    BLOCK
264757  9/24/2021   3:59:58 PM  RUN     SWEEP
264758  9/24/2021   3:59:58 PM  AAPL    BLOCK
```

**What I tried?** Currently it's splitting the rows for each day

```
# Export to 7days_split.csv files.
for date, data in options_flow.groupby('CreatedDate'):
    data.to_csv("{}.csv".format(date))
```

**What I want?**

I want to split the CSV on the `CreatedDate` column by 7 days range e.g 1st CSV will contain rows of the first 7 days, 2nd CSV will continue rows next 7 day's and so on.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Grouping by date range with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46839032/grouping-by-date-range-with-pandas)